# How to check exist element with jquery validate plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How to check exist element with jQuery validate plugin? This is my code:

```
$("#frmNewProject").validate({
    rules: {
        minBudget: { required: true, number: true, min: 300000 },
        maxBudget: { required: true, number: true, max: 150000000 },
        txtDay:    { required: true, number: true, max: 60, min: 1 },
        projectName:     { required: true },
        txtDescription:  { required: true },
        selectedSkills0: { required: true },
        selectedSkills1: { required: true }
    }
});
```

but when selectedSkills1 is removed from page(selectedSkills1.length==0) form submitted.
And I do not want the element does not exist, Do not submit Form

Comment: What input type is selectedSkills1?

Comment: What?  If you don't want the form submitted without `selectedSkills1`, then why are you allowing it to be removed in the first place?

Comment: -1 and a vote to close. You have not explained anything very well here.  What are those?  `text`, `textarea`, `radio`, `checkbox`, etc?  Show the relevant HTML and explain how these items are being "removed from page".

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#frmNewProject").validate({
    rules: {
         selectedSkills1: { 
                  required:{
                  depends: function(element) {
                       return $('#selectedSkills1').length !== 0;
                  }
         }
      }
  }
});
```

**Update**

here is the bin which will help you. http://jsbin.com/otAGuLur/1/ i have also updated my answer.

Comment: While this code may or may not solve the problem (I'm to competent to judge), this answer would be a lot more useful if you explained why you're proposing this code, why you think it solves the problem.

Comment: How are you able to provide an answer when the OP has not shown any HTML or adequately explained what he wants to do?

Comment: Your answer will not work... you cannot make a rule depend upon itself!  You should have tried it out:  http://jsfiddle.net/vkVL2/ ~  By default, if you make a non-existent field required, nothing will happen... it's just pointless.  In other words, there's no practical reason to test if the field exists before applying a rule to itself.

Comment: here is the bin which will help you. http://jsbin.com/otAGuLur/1/ i have also updated my answer.

Comment: **You just created a really verbose and totally pointless version of `required` that functions no differently than `required: true`**.  By default, if you make a non-existent field `required`, nothing will happen.  In other words, there's no reason to test if a field exists before applying rules to this field.  See how [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/8Wb4M/) functions exactly the same as [`required: true`](http://jsfiddle.net/8Wb4M/1/).